# Problema con el ingreso del género de una persona

Tags: java

En este problema debo verificar que la entrada de un usuario sea M,F,m o f. Si la cadena es mayor que uno, se debe volver a pedir el género. 
Si es posible cuando la persona ingrese por ejemplo 'FA', la respuesta se vuelva A. Sin embargo, esta última sentencia no es necesaria.
Lamentablemente, mi código no funciona.

Agradecería mucho la ayuda.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ejercicio_1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String _genero;
    char _newGenero=0;
    int _longitud;
    boolean _valor;


    Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Ingrese su género (M/F): ");
    _genero= stdIn.nextLine();
    _longitud=_genero.length();

    while(_longitud>1) {
        System.out.println("El programa solo acepta un caracter."
                + "\nVuelva a intentarlo");
        System.out.print("Ingrese su género (M/F): ");
        _genero= stdIn.nextLine();
        _longitud=_genero.length();
    }


    if(_longitud==1) {
            _genero = Character.toString(_newGenero);//convertir en char

            if(_newGenero=='M'||_newGenero=='F'||_newGenero=='m'||_newGenero=='f') {

                System.out.println("Su género ha sido registrado");
            }

            else {
                System.out.print("No es una letra válida."
                        + "\n Ingrese su género otra vez: ");
                _newGenero= stdIn.nextLine().charAt(0);
                _valor=true;
                while(_valor) {


                    if(_newGenero=='M'||_newGenero=='F'||_newGenero=='m'||_newGenero=='f') {

                        System.out.println("Su género ha sido registrado");
                        _valor=false;
                    }


                }

            }               

    }



}//fin del main

}//fin de la clase Ejercicio_1
```

Comment: ¿Por qué no funciona? ¿Tienes errores del compilador? ¿Puedes aportar más información a tu pregunta?

Answer (score 3):

Te complicas mucho la vida con tanto if y lógica por separado te lo he puesto todo en una función que lo deja mucho mas claro

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.print("Ingrese su género (M/F): ");
        Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input= stdIn.nextLine();

        while(!validInput(input)) {
            System.out.println("Error texto incorrecto.\nVuelva a intentarlo");
            System.out.print("Ingrese su género (M/F): ");
            input= stdIn.nextLine();
        }

        System.out.println("Su género ha sido registrado");
    }

    private static Boolean validInput(String input) {
        if (input.length() != 1 || (!input.toUpperCase().equals("M") && !input.toUpperCase().equals("F")))
                return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: oohh, muchas gracias

Comment: de nada para eso estamos!